# Tension of a String

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, topological-field-theory, cosmic-string

does anybody know a general relation between the tension of a string and it's energy density? I am at the moment learning about topological cosmic strings and calculated the energy density, now I do not know how to get to the string tension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cosmic string, its energy per unit length and its tension are the same quantity. This is analogous to surface tension, which is the same thing as a liquid's  surface energy per unit area.